# Python igraph TypeError: unhandled type

Tags: python, network-programming, igraph

I am calculating weighted centrality measures using python-igraph.

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Read_Ncol("sample.txt",names=True,directed=False,weights=True)
print (g.vs["name"])
print (g.es["weight"])
```

Below is two lists about the verticles and edge weights in my network:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
[4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0]
```

I am using following codes calculating weighte centrality:

```
print (g.strength(weights=True))
print (g.betweenness(weights=True))
```

Below is the error message I got:

```
TypeError: unhandled type
```

Can anyone let me know what went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pass the `weights` into the functions.
Use this:**

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Read_Ncol("sample.txt",names=True,directed=False,weights=True)
print (g.vs["name"])
print (g.es["weight"])

print (g.strength(weights=g.es["weight"]))
print (g.betweenness(weights=g.es["weight"]))
```